# i am getting org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException in project with saveOrUpdate method with hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

in my local system it working with out any problem. my local system is windows 7 but exception coming randomly in production server which is linux.
i am sharing code please guide me. this exception coming in same location only what is the reason.

> Exception occurring at saveOrUpdate method

---

```
billSubmissionBean.setMasterProviderId(String.valueOf(masterProvider.getMasterProviderId()));
        masterBill.setMasterProvider(masterProvider);
        masterBill.setTransactionType(transactionType);
        billSubmissionDao.save(masterBill, MasterBill.class);

    BillSubmission billSubmission = getBillSubmissionFromBean(billSubmissionBean, user);
    billSubmission.setMasterBill(masterBill);
    billSubmission.setBillSubmissionNumber(masterBill.getBillSubmissionNumber());
    billSubmission.setMasterProviderId(masterProvider.getMasterProviderId());
    billSubmission.setTransactionType(transactionType);

    billSubmission.setApiFlg(Boolean.TRUE);
    if(StringUtils.strToBoolean(billSubmissionBean.getGenerateBillDocument())) {
        billSubmission.setBillDocumentFlg(Boolean.TRUE);
    }
    billSubmissionDao.save(billSubmission, BillSubmission.class);

    List<BillingServiceBean> billingServicesList = billSubmissionBean.getServices();
    if(billingServicesList != null) {
        List<BillService> billServicesList = new ArrayList<BillService>();
        for (BillingServiceBean billServiceBean : billingServicesList) {
            BillService billService = getBillServiceFromBillServiceBean(billServiceBean, user, billSubmissionBean.getGenerateBillDocument());
            billService.setBillSubmission(billSubmission);
            billServicesList.add(billService);
        }
        log.info("Bill services size : " + billServicesList.size());
        if(billingServicesList.size() > 0) {
            billSubmissionDao.saveOrUpdateAll(billServicesList);//this location
        }
    }
```

excption :

> org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate
>   flushing: could not insert: [gov.nysif.model.BillService];
>   uncategorized SQLException for SQL [insert into nysif.bill_service
>   (bill_submission_id, service_place, service_procedure,
>   service_modifiers, dx_pointer, service_days, billed_amount,
>   service_ndc, service_ndc_qty, anesthesia_start, anesthesia_end,
>   revenue_code, dos_from_dt, dos_to_dt, created_dt, created_user,
>   modified_dt, modified_user, non_covered_charges, bill_service_id)
>   values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)];
>   SQL state [55000]; error code [0]; This statement has been closed.;
>   nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This statement
>   has been closed.  at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.convertJdbcAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:726)

Comment: Try to see if your are passing the parameters in correct order.

Comment: this exception not coming repeatedly with same data, more over it working fine with window 7 . problem with linux

Comment: may be related to this http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4CE64998.1080305@proventis.net